# Binding data using Node.js FFI (javascript & c)

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, bind, node-ffi

I'm using [node ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) to call a c library, and I have some issues using this code :

This c program create a folder in the current directory and return 1 if no error.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int create(int dir) 
{
int id;
id = mkdir(dir, S_IRWXU);   
if (id == -1)
  return 1;
else
  return 2;
}
```

the javascript code I'm using to call this c program is :

```
var FFI = require("../lib/ffi");
var libsender = new FFI.Library("./libsender", {"create": [ "int", [ "int" ] ] });


if (process.argv.length < 3) {
console.log("Arguments: " + process.argv[0] + " " + process.argv[1] + " <max>");
process.exit();
}

var output;
output = libsender.create(process.argv[2])
console.log("Your output: " + output);
```

This program is working just if I use int instead of char in the create function (like shown), but I need to use char * in this function. So if I change the function to `create(char * dir)` I't does not work.

I tried to change the call in the js from

`{"create": [ "int", ["int"] ] })`;

to

`{"create": [ "int", ["char *"] ] });`.

can you help with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `int create(int dir)` to `int create(char* dir)`, and…

```
var libsender = new FFI.Library("./libsender", { "create": [ "int", [ "int" ] ]
```

…to…

```
var libsender = new FFI.Library("./libsender", { "create": [ "int", [ "string" ] ]
```